# How can I determine the json path to a field within a record without actually hard coding the path?

Tags: reflection, f#

I would like to work with the following type

```
type RecordPath<'a,'b> = {
    Get: 'a -> 'b
    Path:string
}
```

It's purpose is to define a getter for going from record type `'a` to some field within `'a` of type `'b`. It also gives the path to that field for the json representation of the record.

For example, consider the following fields.

```
type DateWithoutTimeBecauseWeirdlyDotnetDoesNotHaveThisConcept = {
    Year:uint
    Month:uint
    Day:uint
}

type Person = {
    FullName:string
    PassportNumber:string
    BirthDate:DateWithoutTimeBecauseWeirdlyDotnetDoesNotHaveThisConcept
}

type Team = {
    TeamName:string
    TeamMembers:Person list
}
```

An example `RecordPath` might be

```
let birthYearPath = {
    Get = fun (team:Team) -> team.TeamMembers |> List.map (fun p -> p.BirthDate.Year)
    Path = "$.TeamMember[*].BirthDate.Year" //using mariadb format for json path
}
```

Is there some way of letting a library user create this record without ever actually needing to specify the string explicitly. Ideally there is some strongly typed way of the user specifying the fields involved. Maybe some kind of clever use of reflection?

It just occurred to me that with a language that supports macros, this would be possible. But can it be done in F#?

PS: I notice that I left out the s in "TeamMembers" in the path. This is the kind of thing I want to guard against to make it easier on the user.

Comment: I think there might be an answer here involving code quotations. If I figure it out, I will post it.

Comment: You have a getter and you have a json path, both "pointing" at the same field. What do you want to use the json path for?

Comment: @scrwtp I am making a nosql library on top of a rdms that supports foreign keys and other shortcomings of cosmos and mongo. I pretty much have a solution for this particular question involving code quotations which I will post tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, cool. It doesn't explain what you need a json path for, though.

Comment: The json path is so that the rdms knows how to generate a computed column which can be indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in the comments, F# has a quotation mechanism that lets you do this. You can create those explicitly using `<@ ... @>` notation or implicitly using a somewhat more elengant [automatic quoting mechanism](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/AutoQuotationDesignAndSpec.md). The quotations are farily close representations of the F# code, so converting them to the desired path format is not going to be easy, but I think it can be done.

I tried to get this to work at least for your small example. First, I needed a helper function that does two transformations on the code and turns:

- `let x = e1 in e2` into `e2[x <- e1]` (using the notation `e2[x <- e1]` to mean a subsitution, i.e. expression `e2` with all occurences of `x` replaced by `e1`)
- `e1 |> fun x -> e2` into `e2[x <- e1]`

This is all I needed for your example, but it's likely you'll need a few more cases:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let rec simplify dict e = 
  let e' = simplifyOne dict e
  if e' <> e then simplify dict e' else e'

and simplifyOne dict = function 
  | Patterns.Call(None, op, [e; Patterns.Lambda(v, body)]) 
        when op.Name = "op_PipeRight" ->
      simplify (Map.add v e dict) body 
  | Patterns.Let(v, e, body) -> simplify (Map.add v e dict) body 
  | ExprShape.ShapeVar(v) when Map.containsKey v dict -> dict.[v]
  | ExprShape.ShapeVar(v) -> Expr.Var(v)
  | ExprShape.ShapeLambda(v, e) -> Expr.Lambda(v, simplify dict e)
  | ExprShape.ShapeCombination(o, es) -> 
      ExprShape.RebuildShapeCombination(o, List.map (simplify dict) es)
```

With this pre-processing, I managed to write an `extractPath` function like this:

```
let rec extractPath var = function
  | Patterns.Call(None, op, [Patterns.Lambda(v, body); inst]) when op.Name = "Map" ->
      extractPath var inst + "[*]." + extractPath v.Name body
  | Patterns.PropertyGet(Some(Patterns.Var v), p, []) when v.Name = var -> p.Name
  | Patterns.PropertyGet(Some e, p, []) -> extractPath var e + "." + p.Name
  | e -> failwithf "Unexpected expression: %A" e
```

This looks for (1) a call to `map` function, (2) a property access on a variable that represents the data source and (3) a property access where the instance has some more property accesses.

The following now works for your small example (but probably for nothing else!)

```
type Path = 
  static member Make([<ReflectedDefinition(true)>] f:Expr<'T -> 'R>) = 
    match f with
    | Patterns.WithValue(f, _, Patterns.Lambda(v, body)) ->
      { Get = f :?> 'T -> 'R
        Path = "$." + extractPath v.Name (simplify Map.empty body) }
    | _ -> failwith "Unexpected argument"

Path.Make(fun (team:Team) -> team.TeamMembers |> List.map (fun p -> p.BirthDate.Year))
```

Comment: I solved it in a different (simpler?) way. Can you see any problems with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this is

```
let jsonPath userExpr = 
    let rec innerLoop expr state =
        match expr with
        |Patterns.Lambda(_, body) ->
            innerLoop body state
        |Patterns.PropertyGet(Some parent, propInfo, []) ->
            sprintf ".%s%s" propInfo.Name state  |> innerLoop parent
        |Patterns.Call (None, _, expr1::[Patterns.Let (v, expr2, _)]) when v.Name = "mapping"->
            let parentPath = innerLoop expr1 "[*]"
            let childPath = innerLoop expr2 ""
            parentPath + childPath
        |ExprShape.ShapeVar x ->
            state
        |_ -> 
            failwithf "Unsupported expression: %A" expr
    innerLoop userExpr "" |> sprintf "$%s"

type Path = 
  static member Make([<ReflectedDefinition(true)>] f:Expr<'T -> 'R>) = 
    match f with
    |Patterns.WithValue(f, _, expr) ->
        let path = jsonPath expr
        {
            Get = f :?> 'T -> 'R
            Path = path
        }
    | _ -> failwith "Unexpected argument"
```

Caveat: I don't know enough about these techniques to tell if Tomas' answer performs better in some edge cases than mine.

Comment: Implementing quotation translations like this is always a bit tricky and easy to get wrong. My approach is fairly conservative in that it works for the example, but should not accept invalid arguments (and possibly some valid - which you need to add). This is mainly done by keeping track of the variable representing the "current value" - I think your code may get it wrong if there were some other variables (perhaps captured from the outside of the lambda). But finding the right balance between correct & not too complicated is hard here!

Comment: For example, if you have `let x = System.DateTime.Now` and then use `Path.Make(fun y -> x.Year)`, then I think your code will not detect that this is a wrong argument, but instead return `$.Year`.

Comment: Ok good to know. I will spend some time understanding your code a bit more.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I tried your captured local variable idea to see how it fails. It does not compile.  Apparently "A quotation may not involve an assignment to or taking the address of a captured local variable". I will try to find some other example where the 2 approaches differ.

Comment: After playing with your version a bit, I think it actually works pretty well. The only way to get something unexpected I could find was to insert bogus lambda, i.e. `Path.Make(fun (team:Team) (x:int) -> team.TeamName)`. You can also (in both approaches) use unsupported property like `Path.Make(fun (team:Team) -> team.TeamName.Length)`.